# Login failed for user ''. using UserAssignedManagedIdentity while fetching data from AzureSQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, azure-managed-identity

I have created a Managed Identity (User Assigned) using Azure portal.

I attached that MSI with Azure App Service

Added appropriate permissions for the MSI at Azure SQL (Database)

In this implementation I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 2.2.6

I have the following code :

**IDBAuthTokenService.cs**

```
public interface IDBAuthTokenService
{
    Task<string> GetTokenAsync();
}
```

**AzureSqlAuthTokenService.cs**

```
public class AzureSqlAuthTokenService : IDBAuthTokenService
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public AzureSqlAuthTokenService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{ManagedIdentityClientId = _configuration[C.AppKeys.UserAssignedClientId]});
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[]{_configuration[C.AppKeys.AzureSQLResourceId]});
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, default);
        return token.Token;
    }
}
```

**TestDbContext.cs:**

```
public partial class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext()
    {
    }

    public TestDbContext(IDBAuthTokenService tokenService, DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection() as SqlConnection;
        connection.AccessToken = tokenService.GetTokenAsync().Result;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<HealthCheckData> HealthCheckData { get; set; }
}
```

**TestReportServiceProvider.cs**

```
public class TestReportServiceProvider : IReportService
{
    private readonly TestDbContext _objDBContext;
    public TestReportServiceProvider(TestDbContext objDBContext)
    {
        _objDBContext = objDBContext;
    }

    public dynamic GetDataDetails(ReportDTO filters)
    {
        var response = new TestReponseExcelDto();
        var ds = new DataSet();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_objDBContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString))
        {
            
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "[CR].[LoadProcedureDetailPopup]";
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand = command;
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            response.Data = GetData(ds.Tables[0]);
            response.TotalEngagements = response.Data.Select(d => d.TestReviewId).Distinct().Count();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

In the above code while debugging I found error: Login failed for user ''. just after the control passes the code snippet connection.Open();. Even though the AccessToken was setup at the constructor within the TestDbContext , in this case I noticed that it is assigned with null value.

I added the below code before opening the connection and it started working fine as expected:

```
connection.AccessToken = ((SqlConnection)_objDBContext.Database.GetDbConnection()).AccessToken;
```

Even though my fix is solving the issue, I wanted to know whether it is correct way of doing  it or are there better ways to manage it.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: if you are using EF Core, you should have use dbContext object to perform Database operations instead of ADO.Net process like connection.open()

Comment: Keep only server and database in connection string as it is using MSI. Add that MSI in SQL Server Identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-azure-ad-user-assigned-managed-identity?view=azuresql

Comment: Thanks @Nayan for your response. I do have server and database in the connectionstring excluding the userId and password details. Here in this case it is mixed implementation of EFCore 2.2.6 and ADO.NET along with System.Data.SqlClient. The problem happens when a connction is opened in the method: GetDataDetails(ReportDTO filters).

Comment: for SqlClient of 3.0+ should have Authentication and User Id (Client Id of MSI) in connection string. for 2.1 User Id is Object Id of MSI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-managed-identity-authentication

Comment: In this case I am using System.Data.SqlClient version: 4.6.1. My issue why is the token value set to null even though it is setup in the TestDbContext constructor. Hence I am setting it once again in the method: GetDataDetails(ReportDTO filters) before the connection is opened for performing any database operations